# PHP table only displaying one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a problem in retrieving data from my ***MySQL*** table. My script only retrieves one row, which is the last row from my *table*, wherein the table contains 12 filled rows. My aim is to retrieve all rows in the table.

Here is the section of the code I believe the problem stems from:

```
<?php
//Grabs the whole queston list
$question_list="";
$sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM DebateQuestion") or die(mysql_error());;
$questionCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);// count the output amount

if($questionCount>0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$id = $row["qQuestionNo"];
$question = $row["qQuestion"];
$venue = $row["qDebateVenue"];
$date = $row["qDate"];
$question_list = "$id. $question&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#'>Edit</a> &bull;<a href='#'>Delete</a><br/>";
}
}else{
$question_list = "There are no questions in the inventory yet";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
$question_list = "$id. $question&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#'>Edit</a> &bull;<a href='#'>Delete</a><br/>";
```

Make sure you append the text, not overwrite the previous value! Use `.=` to append strings:

```
$question_list .= "$id. $question&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#'>Edit</a> &bull;<a href='#'>Delete</a><br/>";
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I have been trying to get my head around this for days. Quick question what do u mean by the phrase 'Make sure you append the text'

Comment: At the first lines you initialize your variable `$question_list` as an empty string, this is good! During your iteration over the table rows (inside the `while`) you want to fill this variable. This is done by appending the HTML (adding at the end of the content that is already there) for each row of your table. This is done with `.=`. Your code simply overwrites the previous contents on each iteration, so you end up with only the last record

Comment: Thanks a lot... Point taken